# Angular subscribe property doesnt exist on object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I know I need to make an interface here but the issue is that I'm subscribing so I can't add it. What are my other options?

```
login(form: NgForm) {
    this.authService.login(form.value.email, form.value.password).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.authService.setToken(result.token);
        this.authService.setUserId(result.userId);
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.presentToast(error.error.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

Auth service login function

```
login(email: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/login',
      {email: email, password: password}
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal Stackblitz example?

Comment: Your code will work. You get an error because `authService login` does not return anything. (the method) `: Observable` or something.

Comment: Voting to close this as a typographical error as it's just missing a return statement in the login method

Answer (score 0):

This one should work as I tried

**Service**

```
login(email: String, password: String)
    {
       return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/login', {email: email, password: password}).pipe(map((response:any)=>{
         const result=response;
         if(result){
            this.setToken(result.token);
            this.setUserId(result.userId);
         }
       }))
    }
```

**Component**

```
login() {
        this.authService.login(form.value.email, form.value.password).subscribe(
          result => {
             //form values should be cleared after login
             form.value.email="";
             form.value.password="";
          },
          error => {
            this.alertService.presentToast(error.error.message);
          }
        );
      }
```